# Interactive map in a closed network

Tags: python, maps, geospatial

I have geo coordinates data that i need to display on a map in a closed network.

Most libraries related to maps require an internet connection folium or map box.

As such i have no idea where or how to begin.

Comment: You could download a shapefile and then use the shapefile with geopandas.

Comment: Geopandas also itself comes with some preloaded datasets, such as a world map which is what you might be looking for, so you won't even need to download shapefiles. [This might be of some help](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/mapping.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(requires a Linux system)

Credit to this [guide](https://www.gibbard.me/openstreetmap/).

Download the area of the map you wish to display from [geofabrik](https://download.geofabrik.de/index.html)
set up a localized tile server using a docker run the following to set up the docker :

```
docker volume create openstreetmap-data
# For the fastest possible import time, increase the number of threads to
# match what is available on your CPU.
# You should also increase the amount of memory available to OSM2PGSQL to 
# about 75% of your RAM.
docker run -v <full path to downloaded file>:/data/region.osm.pbf \
           -v openstreetmap-data:/data/database/ \
           -e THREADS=4 \
           -e "OSM2PGSQL_EXTRA_ARGS=-C 4096" \
           overv/openstreetmap-tile-server:2.2.0 import
```

To initialize the tile server:

```
    # Adjust the threads and memory as required
docker run -p 8080:80 \
           -v openstreetmap-data:/data/database/ -d \
           -e THREADS=4 \
           -e "OSM2PGSQL_EXTRA_ARGS=-C 4096" \
           --shm-size=256m \
           overv/openstreetmap-tile-server:2.2.0 run
```

Go to http://localhost:8080 to check the server

Pre-rendering the map is recommended

```
docker exec -it  <docker_container_name> /bin/bash

# Run this Inside the docker container 
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alx77/render_list_geo.pl/master/render_list_geo.pl
chmod +x render_list_geo.pl
#./render_list_geo.pl -x <left> -X <right> -y <bottom> -Y <top> \
#                     -z 0 -Z <max_zoom> -n <number_of_threads> -m ajt
# For example to render the Isle of Wight from zoom level 7 to 15 using 2 threads
./render_list_geo.pl -x -1.6 -X -1.05 -y 50.57 -Y 50.79 -z 7 -Z 15 -n 2 -m ajt
# Once it completes you can disconnect from the container
exit
```

To download the tile run the following python code using the this expression as an example

python3 tile_download.py -x -1.6 -X -1.05 -y 50.57 -Y 50.79 -Z 15

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# tile_download.py
# Adapted from https://gist.github.com/tonyrewin/9444410 (tonyrewin)
import os
import math
import urllib.request
import os.path
import argparse

def deg2num(lat_deg, lon_deg, zoom):
    lat_rad = math.radians(lat_deg)
    n = 2.0 ** zoom
    xtile = int((lon_deg + 180.0) / 360.0 * n)
    ytile = int((1.0 - math.log(math.tan(lat_rad) + \
                (1 / math.cos(lat_rad))) / math.pi) / 2.0 * n)
    return (xtile, ytile)

def download_url(zoom, xtile, ytile):

    url = "http://localhost:8080/tile/%d/%d/%d.png" % (zoom, xtile, ytile)
    dir_path = "tiles/%d/%d/" % (zoom, xtile)
    download_path = "tiles/%d/%d/%d.png" % (zoom, xtile, ytile)

    if not os.path.exists(dir_path):
        os.makedirs(dir_path)

    if(not os.path.isfile(download_path)):
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, download_path)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-x", type=float, help="Minimum longitude")
    parser.add_argument("-X", type=float, help="Maximum longitude")
    parser.add_argument("-y", type=float, help="Minimum latitude")
    parser.add_argument("-Y", type=float, help="Minimum latitude")
    parser.add_argument("-Z", type=int, help="Maximum zoom level (>=7)")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    # Zoom 0 to 6 download worldwide tiles
    for zoom in range(0,7):
        for x in range(0,2**zoom):
            for y in range(0,2**zoom):
                download_url(zoom, x, y)

    for zoom in range(7, int(args.Z)+1):
        xtile_min, ytile_min = deg2num(float(args.y), float(args.x), zoom)
        xtile_max, ytile_max = deg2num(float(args.Y), float(args.X), zoom)

        print(f"Z:{zoom}, X:{xtile_min}-{xtile_max}, Y:{ytile_max}-{ytile_min}")
        for x in range(xtile_min, xtile_max + 1):
            for y in range(ytile_min, ytile_max - 1, -1):                
                result = download_url(zoom, x, y)
```

To Clean up run:

```
# Identify the name of the openstreetmap-tile-server container
docker ps -a
# Stop the container and delete all data (except the downloaded PNG tiles!)
docker stop <name_of_container>
docker rm <name_of_container>
docker volume rm openstreetmap-data
docker image rm overv/openstreetmap-tile-server:2.2.0
```

Than all that is left is to build a Leaflet web app

good luck